# Using method parameters check to see if array object is equal to another string (objective-C)?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, methods

I'm all self taught so please keep the techincal jargin to a minimum. Theoretically if I had a method and it had a parameter that is the name of an array. How do I check to see if that array index 5 is equal to @"Yes" or @"No". I know it's one of these because its testing to see if the picture is appearing in the veiw controller. Here is an example:

```
-(void)methodName :(NSMutableArray *)arrayNameInMethod {
if ( [NSMutableArray *(arrayNameInMethod) indexOfObject:5] == @"Yes"){
   //Hide a different picture assocciated with the Array
} else {
  //Unhide a different picture assocciated with the Array
};
```

Also how do you do use the parameter "arrayNameInMethod" to replace the object. Basically:

```
if(Picture Clicked and picture is Unhidden) {
  [NSMutableArray *(differentArrayNameInMethod) replaceObjectAtIndex:5 withObject: @"True)
};
```

(this is all in another method)

Comment #2: You can't use the parameters the same way because it's a string. You can't access an array with a name as a string.

Thank you so much!

Comment: `@"Yes"` and `@"No"` are not booleans, they're strings. `@YES` (no quotes, all caps) is an `NSNumber` wrapping the boolean value `YES`.

Comment: A method parameter is just like any other variable; you use it in exactly the same way.

Comment: It doesn't work though.

Comment: The only way I can add, that I know of, booleans is using strings

Comment: No you can add any `NSObject`-derived class to an array; most commonly `NSString` and `NSNumber`.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. If you used real names instead of "methodName" "arrayNameInMethod", at least we could start to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: The "stuff" I'm doing changes each time. And it would also be "subjective" acoording to this site. The way I worded it is to keep it so I can just use it each time and be un-subjective.(sorry for spelling I'm on my phone)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you will need is a dictionary, mapping the name to the array.  I will give a barebones implementation:

```
@interface YourClass()
{
    NSMutableDictionary *_arrayMap;
}
@end

@interface YourClass

- (instancetype)init
{
     self = [super init];
     if (self) {
        // You might do this somewhere else, like viewDidLoad:
        _arrayMap = [NSMutableDictionary new];
     }
     return self;
}

- (void)someMethod
{
    // Some functionality to add a new array:
    // Note the array contains NSNumber and NSString objects:
    _arrayMap[@"sampleName"] = [@[ @(0), @"one", @(2.0), @"three", @(4), @(YES)] mutableCopy];
}

-(BOOL)checkForConditionInArrayNamed:(NSString *)arrayName
{
    BOOL retval = NO;
    NSMutableArray *array = _arrayMap[arrayName];
    if ([array count] > 5) {
        id obj = array[5];
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
            retval = [obj boolValue];
    }
    return retval
};
@end
```

You then call `checkForConditionInArrayNamed:` to check for the condition of the named array and act accordingly.

Comment: I will check this out when I get home.

Comment: It does not work, or I am doing some thing wrong (probably the later). This is what I put:                                                         NSMutableArray *Name = weapons[weaponName];
    if( [NSArray *Name indexOfObject:5] = @"True"); this didn't work even though I had the NSDictionary *weapons set.